# Как можно сделать постепенное исчезание стен?

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр, мобильная-разработка

Привет! Как можно сделать постепенное исчезание стен? Есть персонаж.Если он пробегает через мост, на некоторое время, пока он под мостом, его не видно. Я хочу сделать так, что бы его было видно. Думал добавить триггер, при его активации постепенно меняется альфа канал. Но в мобильном шейдере нельзя менять альфаканал. Варианты опустить камеру не подходят, нужно что бы камера всегда оставалась на одном месте

Comment: Пока сделал так. Пускаю linecast от персонажа в сторону моста. Если linecast попадает в мост, то материал моста меняется на другой из assets store, и на нем постепенно уменьшаю прозрачность

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал еще одну камеру которая имела NearPlane от персонажа и дальше. Размещаете ее внутри основной камеры и когда есть необходимость просветить объекты, можно просто включать эту камеру, а потом